# Getting Error , While Installing the Binaries on BB10 Virtual Machine

Tags: blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

[image]

Hello Everybody , 
             I am using BB _10.0.09 , I am getting error while installation the
  binaries ,please have a look at the attached Screen Shoot.
  Getting Error Message : 
  "Could not find qmake configuration directoryCould not find qmake configuration fileUsing OS scope before setting MAKEFILE_GENERATOR"
  Please suggest me Where I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a solution from this link  http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Native-Development/BB10-Native-Cascades-SDK-not-connecting-to-Alpha-BB10-simulator/td-p/1719865/page/5

reason .. I am not setting the development Mode , by default it set to Device -Debug , when I changed it to Simulator-Debug it is working fine ..